# How to make Advanced Custom Field custom field work in any page?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I created a custom field group and in the rules I set it to show only on home page. Then I created a input inside this field group called 'contact-info'.

So I want to use the informations that I insert in this input in another page outside home. I tried to use

```
<?php the_field('contact-info') ?>
```

but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in a post ID.

```
the_field( 'contact-info', $postId );
```

Where `$postId` is the ID of your home page.